# Ubuntu and windows on dual hard drives

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 15.10, bootloader, support

I had windows 10 installed on a hard drive then I used my laptop to install Ubuntu 15.10 on my other hard drive because I was having problems installing it on my desktop. To get into Linux I have to push f12 at the boot to get to boot options and choose the hard drive with Ubuntu. It boots into windows 10 automatically. Can anyone tell me how I can use grub to choose which os to boot into instead of having to do this.

Comment: Please be specific which device you are using - laptop or desktop and can you see grub menu at all or not?

Comment: My desktop. Has both hard drives in it. One with windows 10 and the other with Ubuntu. It goes straight to windows if I don't do anything so I don't see grub at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you are in Windows - Click Shift plus shutdown and choose the option to boot to Ubuntu. Once you are in Ubuntu then try this.
First let's try to get into Ubuntu and then do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

for more information, please refer this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

This will fix your dual booting. Please follow every instructions in this exercise.

- Make sure if Windows 10 is installed in EFI mode - Ubuntu should also
  be in EFI mode only.
- Disable secure boot in your device.
- Try to install /boot properly